# Can't select image in new Django filer in admin

Tags: django, django-admin, django-filer

I have a problem in a new Django app with filer.
I can upload an image from disk, but I can't select
this image to choose it. There is no arrow to pick up the image.
This is my screen

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iFuB2.png)

Comment: Which version do you use ?